# How to make a simple calculator that includes the math.pow function. the math.pow function throws error

Tags: python, flask

My code is :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request , url_for
import math

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])

def calcualtor ():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = int(request.form['first_number'])
        b = request.form['operator']
        c = int(request.form['second_number'])       
        result = 0.0

        if  b == '+' :
            result = (a+c)
            return render_template('index.html', result = result)     
        elif b == '-' :
            result = (a-c)
            return render_template('index.html', result = result)
        elif b == '*' :
            result = (a*c)
            return render_template('index.html', result = result)
        elif b == '/' :
            result = (a/c)
            return render_template('index.html', result = result)  
        elif  b == '^' :
            result = math.pow(a,b)
            return render_template('index.html', result = result)

    return
```

Other all parts such as addition, subtraction do work as expected but the math.pow doesn't like to work. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

The index.html file has a simple h1{{ result }} to display the result

The error screen is:

```
TypeError
TypeError: must be real number, not str

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\app.py", line 32, in calcualtor
            return render_template('index.html', result = result)
        elif b == '/' :
            result = (a/c)
            return render_template('index.html', result = result)
        elif  b == '^' :
            result = math.pow(a,b)
            return render_template('index.html', result = result)

    return


TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you want to write "result = math.pow(a,c)". The code you have given is doing result = math.pow(a,b) - which is a^b and b is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You have written :-

```
result = math.pow(a, b)
```

This is giving you error.

Write it as:-

```
result = math.pow(a,c)
```